# UIButton.setTitle | Huge delay when changing the title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton and when I use the « setTitle » method it takes from 1 to 20 seconds to actually change the title in my UI.

The action is called from an async server request (when it succeed).

And the most annoying thing is that I also used an « addAction » method on the button and this one is applying instantly.

My button is in a TableViewCell so basically it looks like that :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    boolAlready = false

    findParticipation()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellActions = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(informationsCellArray[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! eventDetailsActions

    if boolAlready {
        cellActions.btnParticipate.setTitle("Annuler", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cellActions.btnParticipate.addTarget(self, action: "deleteParticipation", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    } else {
        cellActions.btnParticipate.setTitle("...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}

func findParticipation() {
    //serverRequest when success :
    boolAlready = true
    print(« ok »)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I really don’t understand, as soon as I get the « print(« ok ») » I can press the button and it launches my target as intended. but the title remains « … » for up to 20 seconds and changes afterwards.

I've tried to do it in the main thread by putting `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}` around my code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do the stuff in main thread

Comment: I still have the same problem... I put `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}` around my code in the findParticipation function.